# Relaunch a View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to use same `View Controller` for showing my `second view` which should be inside `Second View Controller`. The motive is to **reuse** the same `View Controller` for different `View` while not losing the push animation effect.

**See my code below:-**

```
class PictureCaptureVC: UIViewController {

    public var isReviewPhoto = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if isReviewPhoto {
            btnSubmit.isHidden = false
        } else{
            btnSubmit.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction private func handleReviewBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {    
        if let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PictureCaptureVC") as? PictureCaptureVC {
            secondViewController.isReviewPhoto = true
            self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

It is creating a UITransitionView Over the Top View and i am even concerned about memory leaks.

[See This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNX6B.png)

Any Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: In the `handleReviewBtn` function you appear to be instantiating a new view controller from your storyboard then presenting it and immediately trying to dismiss it.  Is this what you are really intending?

Comment: Yes, just get rid of the `self.dismiss....`

Comment: Yes correct, removing self.dismiss.. works well.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth yes correct. i want to dismiss the same view controller and then again present it with some other view

Comment: but if you don't dismiss it, then it keeps on creating UITransitionView

Comment: If you are going to immediately dismiss it why even bother presenting it.  Just create an instance variable for the view controller and hold the reference in there then you can present it whenever you want.